# sql BLOB image to FACEBOOK share using PHP

Tags: php, database, facebook, image, share

I'm trying to integrate facebook share by using images directly from my database.

Static images using the OG tags:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://X.com/image.jpg" />"
```

Works fine.

However, my images are not static, they are being called from my database using this:

```
 echo "<img src=\"pic.php?id=".$id."\"/>";
```

Where pictures render fine on my website but facebook share does not pick them up.

The logical thing in my mind then would be to do this:

```
 echo "<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"http://X.com/pic.php?id=".$id."\"/>";
```

Sadly, this does not work.

Additionally, using rewrite engine to reform the URL:

```
http://x.com/pic/id
http://x.com/pic/id.jpg
```

Does not work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution - but this may help; facebook has a [great tool called Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).  You use it to see how facebook views your URL.  This tool will alert you when your `og:tags` are missing or malformed. 

It can also be used to decode access tokens.